# Url.Action produces querystring, any way to produce full url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently in my project I am using @Url.Action to create links in the href attribute of anchor tags.

for instance:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 10 })' id="btn">Click</a>
```

And this works fine, however the URL produced is...

```
/home/index?id=10
```

is there a way to return the url

```
/home/index/10
```

for SEO and aesthetic purposes? I used an id and number as a placeholder - in the real application it can and will use a string instead (so...

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { name="test" })' id="btn">Click</a>
```

to return the url

```
/home/index/test
```

Comment: `Url.Action` will use your routing table, is that set up correctly to allow this?

Comment: @DavidG It is allowed, as I can use the full URL. However both lead to the same page. `/home/index/test` works - but so does `/home/index?name=test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the routing is correct. Make sure you have a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

For your 'real application', as you are using a parameter called `name` you will need one looking like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```